# AJAX post number as string

Tags: php, ajax

I am new learner and need your support.

i have Echo $ref; ($ref = number) and passing value through AJAX to another page for some operations but this value is always passing as string and if i am using intval($_post(['$ref1']) function it is giving zero value.

php code user will fill the form and click on create new belwo code..

```
<?php
 session_start();

  require "includes/config.php";
  include('header.php');

?>



<div class='container'>

<div style='margin-top:10px'>
  <a href='welcome.php' class='btn btn-primary'>User Profile</a>
  <a href='invsummarymaindd.php' class='btn btn-primary'>Back Invoice Summary</a>
  <a href='logout.php' class='btn btn-danger'>Sign Out of Your Account</a>
 </div>

 <div class='row col-md-12' style='margin-top:15px'>

 <div class='col-md-3'>
   <input type='text' class='form-control' name='vendor' id='vendor' placeholder='Supplier Name'>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-3'>
   <input type='text' class='form-control' name='vendor_email' id='vendor_email' placeholder='email'>
   </div>

   <div class='col-md-3'>
   <input type='text' class='form-control' name='vendor_person' id='vendor_person' placeholder='Name Of Person'>
   </div>

   <div class='col-md-3'>
   <input type='text' class='form-control' name='vendor_phone' id='vendor_phone' placeholder='Phone Number'>
   </div>
</div>

<div class='col-md-3'>
 <button name='create_vendor' class='btn btn-primary' id='create_vendor'> Create Invoice </button>
 <input type='hidden' name='login_user_id' id='login_user_id'>
</div>

</div>
<div id="maindata"></div>

<br/>  <br/>

<br><br>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/operation.js"></script>
```

ajax code full code -  ajax to pass data from one page to another

```
$('#create_vendor').on('click',function() {

  var vendor  = $('#vendor').val();
  var vendor_email  = $('#vendor_email').val();
  var vendor_person  = $('#vendor_person').val();
  var vendor_phone  = $('#vendor_phone').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'vendor_info.php',
            data: 'vendor='+vendor+'&vendor_email='+vendor_email+'&vendor_person='+vendor_person+'&vendor_phone='+vendor_phone,
            success: function(ref2){
               show_details(ref2);
            }
        });
        return false;
 });

 function show_details(ref2){
   $.ajax({

       type: 'POST',
       url: 'vendor_info.php',
       data: 'ref1='+ref2,
       success: function(data){
         console.log(ref2);
         console.log(typeof(ref2));
         $('#maindata').html(data);
       }
    });
    console.log(typeof(ref2));
  }
```

php code to for the inserting data to mysql

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['vendor']) && !empty($_POST['vendor_email']) && !empty($_POST['vendor_person']) && !empty($_POST['vendor_phone'])){
  $max_sql = "SELECT MAX(ID) as max_number FROM supplier";
  $max_result = $mysqli->query($max_sql);

   $max_number = 1;
   while($res=$max_result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $max_number =  $res['max_number'];
     $ref2  = $max_number;
   }

$sql_add = "INSERT INTO  supplier set
        SupplierName = '".$_POST['vendor']."',
        Email = '".$_POST['vendor_email']."',
        PersonName = '".$_POST['vendor_person']."',
        CC = '".$ref2."',
        phone = '".$_POST['vendor_phone']."'";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql_add);
echo $ref2;

}
  ?>
```

after data is inserted data will be shown in the page by passing $ref2 value through ajax, which is number but it is becomming string and when i am using in sql as per below no data is appearing but i use hard number to test it is working

```
<?php
 session_start();

  require "includes/config.php";
  include('header.php');

?>


<?php
if( isset($_POST['ref1']) && ($_POST['ref1'] != "") ){

$q = $_POST['ref1'];

//to check status of $q
echo $q;
echo gettype($q);

if (is_numeric($q)) { echo "Yes"; } else { echo "No"; }
if (is_string($q)) { echo "Yes"; } else { echo "No"; }

        $mquery = "SELECT * FROM  supplier WHERE ID='".$q."'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($mquery);


      echo "<table class='table'>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>SupplierName</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>PersonName</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        </tr>";

      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['SupplierName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['PersonName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

     }

      echo "</table>";
```

looking for the support and code is full

Comment: It's not clear to me specifically what you're describing.  In all of this code, which is the first value that isn't what you expect?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: yes that i know but first i want to resolve number passing from ajax as string...i am learning and slowly slowly i will move

Comment: Are you sure that this query is working fine: `$max_sql = "SELECT MAX(ID) as max_number FROM supplier"`

Comment: yess it is working fine

Comment: preg_match_all('!\d+!', $q, $matches);
print_r($matches);
$var = implode(' ', $matches[0]);

echo "<br>";
echo trim($var); i use this one to check what happening in ref  so i found result -------Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 1 [2] => 3 [3] => 3 [4] => 1 [5] => 298 ) )
8 1 3 3 1 298

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess since we're missing part of the code but I'd start by checking in your browser's network tab that ref1 was actually posted with the right value. The casting it to int() in php should work. I'd guess that since you get the value 0 the variable contains a letter or another character.

Also, you should really look into using prepared statements, otherwise your code is vulnerable to sql injections.

Side note, to simplify your validation you could use empty() which will do isset + compare with "" all in one.

Comment: kindly supports